# Unable to call Firebase Cloud Function from client-side with fetch

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have several Firebase Cloud Functions that follow this syntax:

```
exports.sendText = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {...
```

And that always works fine, but I've been struggling with this new "post" function I recently deployed. This is how it's defined...

```
payment_app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
    const { items } = req.body;

    // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
        currency: "usd",
        automatic_payment_methods: {
            enabled: true,
        },
    });

    res.send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
});
exports.payment = functions.https.onRequest(payment_app)
```

And this is how I call it from the client-side.

```
function buyProduct(id, quantity) {
    fetch('payment_app/create-payment-intent', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            items: [
                { id: id, quantity: quantity }
            ]
        })
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.ok) return res.json()
        return res.json().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
    }).then(({ url }) => {
        console.log(url)
        Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), { target: '_blank', href: url }).click();
        var refreshVerify = setInterval(() => {
            let payment_status = localStorage.getItem("payment_status")
            if (payment_status) {
                clearInterval(refreshVerify)
                localStorage.removeItem("payment_status")
                if (payment_status === "success") {
                    console.log("payment success")
                } else if (payment_status === "cancel") {
                    console.log("payment cancel")
                } else {
                    console.log("error local_payment_status variable not valid")
                }
            }
        }, 1000)
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e.error)
    })
}
```

Doing this returns a 404 not found error:

```
script.js:3849 POST http://localhost:1234/payment_app/create-payment-intent 404 (Not Found)
buyProduct @ script.js:3849
testFunction @ script.js:3845
(anonymous) @ script.js:1257
setTimeout (async)
showApp @ script.js:1242
parcelRequire.script.js.firebase/compat/app @ script.js:1209
newRequire @ script.75da7f30.js:47
(anonymous) @ script.75da7f30.js:81
(anonymous) @ script.75da7f30.js:120
script.js:3880 undefined
```

Could anyone help me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly? If it matters, this is my firebase.json. I think I may be something wrong here?

```
{
  "functions": {
    "engines": {
      "node": "14"
    },
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "payment_app/**",
        "function": "create-payment-intent",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Cloud Functions code you are implementing a **callable** function. From the documentation on callable functions:

> It's important to keep in mind that HTTPS callable functions are similar but not identical to HTTP functions. To use HTTPS callable functions you must use the client SDK for your platform together with the `functions.https` backend API (or implement the protocol).

So you can't simply `fetch()` to call the function, as it doesn't implement the correct protocol. Instead you should call it as shown in the documentation on [calling a function from your client-side application code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function).

In case you're on a client platform for which no callable SDK exists:

> If you want to add similar functionality to an app built on an unsupported platform, see the [Protocol Specification for `https.onCall`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I still can't figure it out but I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. The sample documentation for Stripe elements shows the syntax I described, and I can't figure out how to convert it to the type of function you mentioned.

I've also tried hiring people on Freelancer, and I can't find anyone who can figure it out either. Thank you for helping me figure out what I was doing wrong though, I've been stuck on this for a week now. Maybe if I show someone more experienced this post they'll be able to fix it.

Comment: "I still can't figure it out" What did you try with the information from the links to the documentation I provided? You'll need to either use an SDK to make the call, or implement the correct protocol yourself.

Comment: The link you sent shows the syntax I'm already familiar with of using onCall((data, context)...

But in the Stripe elements documentation:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart

It shows I need to do res.send, but there is no res variable. And if I do context.send, or if I rename the variables req/res instead of data/context it doesn't make a difference, nor would I expect it to.

Every resource I can find to learn this uses Angular/React/Vue/another framework. I'm using vanilla JavaScript on a project that's 99% done, and don't want to use another framework.

Comment: But I can't find any guides or tutorials showing how to do this, and the Stripe documentation shows a completely different syntax than you say needs to be used to call the function, and I've seen every YouTube video I can find, including trying to make sense of videos that use frameworks I'm not familiar with.

So I'm not sure what steps I can take myself to figure this out at this point.

Comment: More likely the Stripe documentation you're referring to is using a regular HTTP function, instead of Firebase's custom Callables. Regular HTTP functions are documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I get "res.send is not a function" when I try to use the syntax in my last post.

I read the link you sent, and it shows the syntax I'm using in my original post. But I don't see where it describes how to call the function from the client side. Does it have something to do with using app.get?

Comment: Are you saying I should leave the function the way I described in my original post instead of converting it? And I just need to figure out how to call it? Or am I declaring the function incorrectly?

Comment: I'm trying to research how to call a post function, and everything says to use fetch. But fetch isn't working, and you said not to use it?

Comment: You will have to choose: either use a Callable function and call it with the Firebase SDK in your client-side code (docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), or your a HTTP function and use e.g. fetch (docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Comment: I'm trying to call it using fetch though, and I'm getting the error described in my original post. So what should I do differently? The link you sent doesn't mention anything about using fetch, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: As said in my original answer to your original post: you're declaring a *Callable* function here `exports.sendText = functions.https.onCall((data, context)` and then trying to call it through `fetch` instead of the SDK. You'll have to implement the client+server from **one** of the links in my previous comments, while you're now mixing from both.

Comment: But again, if I call it using https.onCall((data, context) then how do I do the equivalent of res.send? I just get res/context.send is not a function when I try that syntax...

Comment: I just tried hiring another Freelancer with a lot more experience than me. I sent them this StackOverflow post and they couldn't figure it out either.